# Unable to start PM2 application with json file

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, pm2

I am facing a peculiar issue. I am trying to start my application with pm2 . Without the json file , it works perfectly fine , but when I add a json file and try to start it , it does not hit my application in the first start , but works well if I stop and start the instance again.Also , when the instance is first started if I do pm2 list , the PID number keeps changing continually. Any help on this please?
PM2 json file :

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "ABC",
    "script"      : "./bin/www",
    "watch"       : true,
    "env": {
      "NODE_ENV": "development",
      "PORT":8443
    },
    "env_production" : {
      "NODE_ENV": "production",
      "PORT":4000
   },

    "error_file"      : "err.log",
    "out_file"        : "out.log",
    "merge_logs"      : false
  }]
}
```

Command to start the application with pm2 json file :  pm2 start sample.json
Command to stop the application with pm2 json file : pm2 stop ABC
to kill : pm2 kill

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You might try setting your `exec_mode` to `fork`. If I had to guess, it's starting up with a default mode of `cluster` and it spins up the number of instances equivalent to the number of processors as detected by the system. While this is typically fine for webapps, it's not always suitable for all situations.

You could also try setting `instances` to `1` in `cluster` mode

Answer (score 0):

Your **`PM2-JSON-File`** looks good but how looks like your

**`package.json`**

```
....
"scripts": {
    "start": "node start -p 8443 /bin/www"
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
.....
```